# Type hints: Is it a bad practice to alias primitive data types?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

In Python documentation for typing & type hints we have the below [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases):

```
Vector = List[float]

def scale(scalar: float, vector: Vector) -> Vector:
    return [scalar * num for num in vector]
```

`Vector` type alias clearly shows that type aliases are useful for simplifying complex type signatures.

**However, what about aliasing primitive data types?**

Let's contrast two basic examples of function signatures:

```
URL = str    

def process_url(url: URL) -> URL:
    pass
```

vs.

```
def process_url(url: str) -> str:
    pass
```

Version with type alias `URL` for primitive type `str` is:

- self-documenting (among others, now I can skip documenting returned value, as it should be clearly an url),
- resistant to type implementation change (I can switch URL to be `Dict` or `namedtuple` later on without changing functions signatures).

The problem is I cannot find anyone else following such practice. I am simply afraid that I am unintentionally abusing type hints to implement my own ideas instead of following their intended purpose.

---

**Note from 2020-10**

Python 3.9 introduces "flexible function and variable annotations", which allows to make annotations like:

```py
def speed_1(distance: "feet", time: "seconds") -> "miles per hour":
    pass

def speed_2(
    distance: Annotated[float, "feet"], time: Annotated[float, "seconds"]
) -> Annotated[float, "miles per hour"]:
    pass
```

Which renders aliasing data types for documenting purposes rather redundant!

See:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0593/
- https://realpython.com/python39-new-features/#annotated-type-hints

Comment: No, in some programming languages like Haskell, type aliasses are even very common: if you later change your mind about the `URL` type, then you can simply change it, and all type checking will change. In Python, I occasionally see a class that is defined with two identifiers.

Comment: Note that the signature of ``process_url`` will be the same in either case! Only the source code shows the alias; any usage has no idea which name was used to refer to the basic type. Even in the first case, the actual signature is just ``process_url(url: str) -> str``.

Answer (score 30):

Using an alias to mark the meaning of a value can be misleading and dangerous. If only a subset of values are valid, a [NewType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) should be used instead.

> Recall that the use of a type alias declares two types to be equivalent to one another. Doing `Alias = Original` will make the static type checker treat `Alias` as being **exactly equivalent** to `Original` **in all cases**. This is useful when you want to simplify complex type signatures.

Simple aliasing works both ways: the alias `URL = str` means any `URL` is a `str` *and also means* any `str` is a `URL` – which is usually not correct: A URL is a special kind of `str` and not any can take its place. An alias `URL = str` is a too strong statement of equality, as it cannot express this distinction. In fact, any inspection that does not look at the source code does not see the distinction:

```
In [1]: URL = str
In [2]: def foo(bar: URL):
   ...:     pass
   ...:
In [3]: foo?
Signature: foo(bar: str)
```

Consider that you alias `Celsius = float` in one module, and `Fahrenheit = float` in another. This signals that it is valid to use `Celsius` as `Fahrenheit`, which is wrong.

Unless your types *do* cary separative meaning, you should just take a `url: str`. The name signifies the meaning, the type the valid values. That means that your type should be suitable to separate valid and invalid values!

Use aliases to *shorten* your hints, but use NewType to *refine* them.

```
Vector = List[float]        # alias shortens
URL = NewType("URL", str)   # new type separates
```

Comment: Well, naturally. We are clearly allowed to pass a wrong type here. On the other hand, Python is dynamically typed language. There is no reasonable way to enforce static typing. That is why the question is about type hints/type annotations, which are rather a helpful tool than Python's paradigm changer. Still, thanks for suggesting NewType. Wasn't aware of this!

Comment: Precisely because Python supports duck typing, type hints should be as meaningful as possible. If any ``str`` may be valid, there is nothing wrong in saying so! By not using the base type some special rules are implied, which can be misleading when not actually defined - even if the rule is just "values from a function providing ``URL``s".

Comment: @CapedHero -- you can enforce the static types by using tools like mypy -- it's configurable so you can completely forbid all dynamic typing if you so wish. Anyways, in this case, I agree it's correct to use NewType here -- that way, the type checker can enforce the constraint that not all strings are URLs.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this question is opinion based, but I have a feeling the general agreement would be **this is a good idea, in general**. You state the benefits yourself, not to mention the ability to generalize code etc.

I would venture this is not common practice in Python as the language itself is not very restrictive. In addition, the variable is already called `url` - that is pretty self explanatory. You could argue you might have something called `json_response` or the like, and you expect it to be a `url`, and your method would certainly make it clear, but since Python encourages duck typing, the code usage often gives this hint anyway, and using type aliasing will be just extra safety for an inconsiderate user. It really goes down just to common practices, with no good "do that!" explanation.

Final point - type aliasing, in a sense, is the most primitive version of object oriented programming. You are making it clear what properties you are expecting of this object, in this case the string should be a valid URL.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question one could ask oneself is "the purpose".

I strongly believe in Python's readability is all that matters. 
With this in mind type hinting, even for primitives is quite OK. Even better if type is masked by virtual "enum"-like type that does some self documenting.

That being said - personally I'd go with the first:
URL = str
def process_url(url: URL) -> URL:
    pass

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the general perception but I consider it a good practice for things that repeat often as it gives you a single place to define what is meant.

Ad repetition, considering you have a lot of functions like

```
def foo(url : str):
    """
    :param url: explaining url
    """
```

You'd end up defining url at each of these functions so instead you can do

```
def foo(x : Url):
   pass
```

The trouble with type alias is that you can't document it so I've come to following

```
class _Url(str):
    """
    Here you can document the type
    """

Url = typing.Union[_Url, str]
```

This gets you

1. the behavior of type alias from the call site point of view (no need to cast it)
2. while allowing you to express the value meaning in type and
3. being able to document the type itself

The only downside is that its not immediately obvious what the union means but its technically correct and I think the best that can be done at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it's a good idea to do so. Let's say there are several methods expecting a parameter `id`. They might be a string, sure. But they have completely different meanings, one might be used to identify a `Person`, another one might identify, say, a `Product`. It's not realistic, that within one domain, every mention of `id` should be prefixed with either `person` or `product`.

But consider the following instead:

```js
/**
 * Some nice documentation about business context and an example value
 */
export type PERSON_ID = string 

//... on another place
/**
 * Some nice documentation about business context and an example value
 */
export type PRODUCT_ID = string
```

Then a public method just could just like this:

```js
doSomething(PRODUCT_ID id, ...)
```

This CAN NEVER BE CONFUSED with another type of ID. And additionally, the IDE will show your nice documentation for that type when someone calls the method.

And I like that :)