# Python typing: alias vs NewType best practices?

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

I want to define my own type `T` for a `MutableMapping[str, str]`. AFAIK it can be done y type aliasing, or via `NewType`

```py
from typing import MutableMapping, NewType

T_alias = MutableMapping[str, str]
T_new = NewType("T_new", MutableMapping[str, str])
```

The problem is the required syntax to initialize one variable of each kind. The correct initialization (which does not trigger any error in Pylance/Pyright) is:

```py
vn: T_new
va: T_alias

vn = T_new({})
va = {}
```

The assignment of `vn` looks ok to me (although I find a bit awkward to have to pass the empty dict `{}`). However I don't like the assignment of `va` because it does not make clear that `va` is of type `T_alias`.

I tried:

```py
va = T_alias({})
```

but it does not work (`Expected no arguments to "MutableMapping" constructor`). So I tried also:

```py
va = T_alias()
```

but it did not work either. Although Pylance does not trigger any error (which may be considered a Pylance bug?), an exception happens at runtime: `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MutableMapping with abstract methods __delitem__, __getitem__, __iter__, __len__, __setitem__`

So the only way to intialize `va` making explicit that it is of type `T_alias` is using `typing.cast`:

```py
va = cast(T_alias, {})
```

which I find awkward too.

So the question is: am I undestanding correctly the use of type aliases and `NewType`? And also, which one would be advised for this particular case? I find the initialization of `T_new` objects cleaner (I don't like the `cast()`) but, I'm worried that the `NewType()` would introduce some overhead when dealing with these objects, and I don't really need to sublcass the dict, so I would prefer to use the alias.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hints: Is it a bad practice to alias primitive data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504347/type-hints-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-alias-primitive-data-types)

Comment: You can just do `va: T_alias = {}`, surely?

Comment: @AlexWaygood Yes, but still I would prefer `va: T_alias = T_alias()` since this hides implementation details such as `T_alias` being a dict.

Comment: Well, you can't instantiate `MutableMapping` directly, since that's just an Abstract Base Class. If you want to use your alias to instantiate a class directly, you have to alias a class that can actually be instantiated. You *could* do this by aliasing `dict[str, str]` instead of `MutableMapping[str, str]` — but see @MisterMyagi's excellent answer he's linked to above for why that's probably a bad idea in Python.