# When to use NewType and when to assign in python

Tags: python, python-typing

Reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) I found that I could use the `NewType` class to define a new type (Option A). But it seems more natural to use Option B. Does option B work?

```py
from typing import List, Union
import torch
# option A
from typing import NewType
Point = NewType('Point', Union[List[int], torch.Tensor])
# option B
Point = Union[List[int], torch.Tensor]
```

Comment: Option B works perfecly fine!. The typing way is what the docs says, but is too verbose. I personally like the other one!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hints: Is it a bad practice to alias primitive data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504347/type-hints-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-alias-primitive-data-types)

Answer (score 1):

### Which

Option A does not actually work as a type hint with static checkers, although the code will execute.  Type checkers complain (`Expected class as second argument to NewType`) that although `Union` type expressions are valid types, they are not valid classes.  From the docs:

> The static type checker will treat the new type as if it were a subclass of the original type

If that feels like it confuses types and classes, I admit I'm also confused.  Nevertheless - not all types can safely go in `NewType`.  Only types that are honest-to-god classes.

### When

As for *when* to use `NewType`, [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) suggest that

> This is useful in helping catch logical errors

There's an example below that link, but paraphrased here: `NewType` helps prevent errors like

```py
my_shoe_size=9
# lotsa code
def delete_user(userid: int): ...
# lotsa code
delete_user(userid=my_shoe_size)
```