# Alias for an typable Union

Tags: python, python-typing

I am looking for a way to create a type alias for a `Union` that is typeable.

In my opinion, there is no suitable default type in the `typing` module.

- `Typing.Iterable` is an `iterable`, which could be a `dict` — but it shouldn't be.
- `typing.Sequence` is a `sequence`, which supports access by integer indices, but this doesn't include `set`s.

---

Imagine I have these variables (which could of course also be parameters of a method):

```py
x : list[str] | tuple[str] | set[str] | frozenset[str]
y : list[str] | tuple[str] | set[str] | frozenset[str]
z : list[int] | tuple[int] | set[int] | frozenset[int]
```

This is basically always the same.

Therefore I would like to create a type alias for it. Something like this:

```py
my_type = list | tuple | set | frozenset
```

so that I can annotate them, like:

```py
x: my_type[str] = ["foo", "bar"]
y: my_type[str] = ["baz", "bar"]
z: my_type[int] = [1, 7, 42]
```

But this gives me this error:

```py
TypeError: There are no type variables left in list | tuple | set | frozenset
```

When I define my type with `Union` (`my_type = typing.Union[list, tuple, set, frozenset]`) instead of the `|` shorthand, I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-professional/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 312, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 1058, in __getitem__
    _check_generic(self, params, len(self.__parameters__))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 228, in _check_generic
    raise TypeError(f"{cls} is not a generic class")
TypeError: typing.Union[list, tuple, set, frozenset] is not a generic class
```

How can I create my type alias to make this work? It should work with python>=3.10.

Comment: With python 3.12 type parameter syntax you can do `type my_type[T] = list[T] | tuple[T] | set[T] | frozenset[T]`

Comment: @joel I don't think so. If I omit the callable part and just write `T = typing.TypeVar("T", list, tuple, set, frozenset) // x: T[str] = ["foo", "bar"]` it results in `TypeError: 'TypeVar' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: yeah that's not what I meant. I meant basically what the accepted answer is. I still think this a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you need a type alias which is generic over some type `_T`. If that's the case, for python>=3.10
you can make use of `TypeAlias` & `TypeVar`.

```
from typing import TypeAlias, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar("_T")

ListOrTupleOrSetOrFrozenSet: TypeAlias = list[_T] | tuple[_T] | set[_T] | frozenset[_T]
x: ListOrTupleOrSetOrFrozenSet[str] = ["1"]
```

And in python 3.12 you could also use the builtin type parameter syntax which also support generic.

```
type ListOrTupleOrSetOrFrozenSet[T] = list[T] | tuple[T] | set[T] | frozenset[T]
x: ListOrTupleOrSetOrFrozenSet[str] = ["1"]
```

See also:

- [How do you alias a type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045222/how-do-you-alias-a-type-in-python/76558166#76558166)

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. Nice to see that with python 3.12 it works more intuitively then. But it should still work with older versions, so your first version is perfect.